# C# текст без учета Escape-последовательностей

Tags: c#, escape

Требуется запустить приложение с определенными параметрами, но при написании пути к файлу VisualStudio выдает ошибку неизвестная Escape-последовательность.
Мне требуется вставить следющий фрагмент в код + "\" + соовтетсвенно VisualStudio видит это как двойные ковычки вместо тескстового \

```
Process.Start("java -Xms" + RAMCHANGE + "m -Xmx" + RAMCHANGE + "m -cp " + appdata  + "\");
```

Answer (score 2):

В языках, основанных на C (в частности, C#), обратный слэш (`\`) внутри строковой константы есть первый символ escape-последовательности. Например, `\n` означает символ с кодом 0x10. Поэтому сам символ `\` так просто не ввести. Необходимо использовать его дважды: `"\\"`. Первый `\` начинает escape-последовательность, второй представляет собой сам нужный символ.

Comment: Или добавлять символ % перед строкой, что бы избежать дублирования символов эскейп последовательности.

Comment: @КириллКирьянчиков: Угу, если вы имели в виду `@`.

Comment: Точно, символ @.

Comment: Работает! Спасибо!

Comment: @PaulPerkov: Пожалуйста!